# How to separate the following fraction into partial fractions?

Tags: partial-fractions

I have that

$$\frac{x^2(1-x)}{(1-x)^3} = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}  -\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^3} $$

Assuming we begin by cancelling the $(1-x)$ on top with one of those on the bottom, how do we go about splitting $\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x)^{2}}$ into the two partial fractions shown (previously, I have only dealt with partial fractions where the denominator power is greater than the numerator). All help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the first step should be$$\frac{x^2(1-x)}{(1-x)^3}=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}.$$And now note that\begin{align}\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}&=\frac{\bigl((x-1)+1\bigr)^2}{(x-1)^2}\\&=\frac{(x-1)^2+2(x-1)+1}{(x-1)^2}\\&=1+\frac{2(x-1)+1}{(x-1)^2}\\&=1+\frac2{x-1}+\frac1{(x-1)^2}.\end{align}

Comment: how did you get $2?$ that should be $x - \frac{2x - 1}{(x-1)^2} = x - \frac{2}{x-1} + \frac1{(x-1)^2}$

Comment: @Ilya I made a mistake, but I've edited my answer.

Comment: Is it now correct? Where does the $(x-1)$ on the 2nd bottom line come from (shouldn't the $(x-1)^{2}$ on top and bottom cancel completely)?

Comment: @rainingagain *Now* it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaylines{{x^2(1-x)\over (1-x)^3}={x^2\over (x-1)^2}={x^2-1\over (x-1)^2} +{1\over (x-1)^2} \\
=
{(x-1)+2\over x-1}+{1\over (x-1)^2}=1+{2\over x-1}+{1\over (x-1)^2}}$$